# Laravel Excel maatwebsite validar planilha antes de importar para o banco de dados

Tags: laravel, arquivo, csv, validação, laravel-8

Estou tentando validar uma planilha antes de importa-la ao banco de dados, preciso verificar se existe alguma data acima da data de hoje no arquivo, mas apenas consigo verificar a primeira linha sendo que pode haver várias datas em linhas aleatórias.
Minha função de import no controller:

```
public function Import(Request $request){
    $contador = 0;
    $today_carbon = Carbon::today()->toDateString();
    $request->validate(['arquivo'=>'required|mimes:csv']);
    $arquivo    = $request->file('arquivo');
    $planilha = Excel::toArray(new UserImport,$arquivo);
    foreach($planilha as $p){
        foreach($p as $i){
            $contador++;
            $colunas = count($i);
            $data = $i[2];
            if($today_carbon >= $data){
                Excel::import(new UserImport,$arquivo);
                return redirect('formulario')->with('sucesso','importação concluida');
            }else{
                return redirect('formulario')->with('erro','erro,não pode ter datas acima de hoje');
            }
            if($colunas == 3){
                Excel::import(new UserImport,$arquivo);
                return redirect('formulario')->with('sucesso','importação concluida');
            }else{
                return redirect('formulario')->with('erro','erro,estrutura incorreta');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Meu modelo de importação:

```
    class UserImport implements ToModel{
    use Importable , SkipsErrors;

    
    public function model(array $row){
        
            return new User([
                'nome'    => $row[0], 
                'cpf' => $row[1],
                'data_venda' => $row[2]
            ]);  
    }

}
```

Quando dou um `dd($planilha);` na variável que transforma a planilha num array fica desse jeito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que vai demorar mais para importar a planilha por fazer varias verificações ainda mais em arquivos com mais de 20k de linhas, mas o que esta faltando? esta seria a melhor solução?